# Error updating SAPUI5 version using UI5 Tooling

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I have a pretty standard ui5.yaml setup as follows..

```
specVersion: "2.3"
metadata:
  name: itcpc.cms
type: application
framework:
  name: SAPUI5
  version: "1.84.26"
  libraries:
    - name: sap.ui.core
    - name: sap.m
    - name: sap.tnt
    - name: themelib_sap_fiori_3
server:
  customMiddleware:
    - name: odataProxy
      beforeMiddleware: serveResources
```

I've attempted to update the SAPUI5 version like so..

```
$ yarn ui5 use sapui5@latest
```

This correctly updates my ui5.yaml file.

But when I run ui5 serve, I get the following error on the sap.tnt dependency.

```
info normalizer:translators:ui5Framework Using SAPUI5 version: 1.118.0

⚠️  Process Failed With Error

Error Message:
Invalid ui5.yaml configuration for project @openui5/sap.tnt

Unsupported "specVersion"

C:\Users\10119451\.ui5\framework\packages\@openui5\sap.tnt\1.118.0\ui5.yaml:2

1: ---
2: specVersion: "3.0"
   ^
Your UI5 CLI installation might be outdated.
Supported specification versions: "2.3", "2.2", "2.1", "2.0", "1.1", "1.0", "0.1"
For details see: https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/pages/Configuration/#specification-versions

For details, execute the same command again with an additional '--verbose' parameter
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

What steps do I need to take to resolve?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the latest version of the UI5 Tooling in order to use the latest SAPUI5 version. You can install it with `npm i --save-dev @ui5/cli@latest`. Afterwards, increase your specVersion to 3.0, since this is the one the latest SAPUI5 build requires.

You can find more info here: https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/v3/updates/migrate-v3/